# Circuitikz - American voltages doesn't work

Tags: circuitikz, overleaf

I'm trying to put polarity signs to a resistor using `american voltages` but it just doesn't work.

I put this in my header `\usepackage[american voltages]{circuitikz}`
and, following the [CTAN package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf), used this code.

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
  \draw
  (0,0) to[sV]
  (0,2) to[R, v^>=$v_1$]
  (3,2) to[C]
  (3,0) -- (0,0)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

P.S.: I'm using overleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}`. Now it works?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
  \draw
  (0,0) to[sV]
  (0,2) to[R, v^>=$v_1$]
  (3,2) to[C]
  (3,0) -- (0,0)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```